# Remove text if rect is below a certian height d3js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to remove the text values from a bar chart if the y position of the text exceeds a certain value, and i only want that particular text to be removed, not all text.

The problem I have is that the y position isn't evaluated (or so it seems) until after the page has fully loaded, here's that piece of code:

```
.text( function(d) { if(d3.select(this).attr("y") < 10) { "" }
    else { return d["Category" + catInt]; } 
    console.log("Not yet evaluated: " + d3.select(this).attr("y"))
})
```

It returns 12 null values in this case, but if I log the values in a function that executes afterwards I get all positions, like this:

```
function getProp() {
    d3.selectAll(".textEnter").each(function(d) {
        console.log("Evaluated: " + d3.select(this).attr("y"))
    })
}
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Here's the full code: **EDIT:** Fixed **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bsXWkGogPxTtLtUKs8LH?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OR** you could use the `transition.on('end')` callback and add texts in the following way:

```
textUpdate.transition()
    .duration(Globalvar.durations)
    .attr("y", function(d) { 
        return y(d["Category" + catInt]) + 15; 
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) { 
        return x(d.month) + x.bandwidth()/2; 
    }).on('end', function(d) { 
       if(d3.select(this).attr("y") < 10) { 
         d3.select(this).text("");
       } else { 
         d3.select(this).text(d["Category" + catInt]);
       } 
       console.log("Evaluated here: " + d3.select(this).attr("y"));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're calling `transition()`, the text is about to undergo transition, and hasn't actually been assigned a `y` attribute at that point in time. Additionally, you are missing a `return` in your first if statement. So the function is just running to the end and returning `undefined`.

You can just re-use your y-scaling function to check for the future value of `y`. I used this in your Plunker code and it shows the labels with this:

```
.text(function(d) { 
    if( y(d["Category" + catInt]) < 10) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return d["Category" + catInt];
    } 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I can't get it to work with that piece of code. If  `y(d["Category" + catInt])` > 300 for example, it still shows the text that has exceeded that value, not sure what I'm missing

Comment: @RobertAndersson Ah, it's because your Y value is coming from the top down, so the shorter the bar the higher the Y value. Try `if( y(d["Category" + catInt]) > height - 50)` and you'll see the October bar's label is now hidden